# Why new Blazor WASM versions supports only .Net 5? What about .NETstandard?

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-standard

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly supports .NETstandard only for version 3.2.1v.
5-6v supports only .Net5 .

Will there be further support .NETstandard?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because .NET standard is deprecated in favor of .NET 5.

> While .NET Standard 2.1 will be the last version of .NET Standard, .NET 5 and all future versions will continue to support .NET Standard 2.1 and earlier. You should think of net5.0 (and future versions) as the foundation for sharing code moving forward.

See Immo's post here:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/

The article specifically mentions Blazor, so might be worth a full read.